# Ajax going straight to error part

Tags: java, php, html, ajax

i dont understand my ajax goes straight to the error part, herewith my code:
please see my comments on the lines im not sure about

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>      
 function validateLogIn(login)
 {
    var username  = $("#username").val();
    var password  = $("#password").val();
    var login  = $("#login").val();
    var remember  = $("#remember").val();
    console.log(username, password, login, remember);
    $.ajax({     
     url: 'php/login.php',                        
     data: {username:username,password:password,login:login,remember:remember},
     type: 'POST',    
     dataType: 'json',      //is this correct??               
     success: function(data)          
    {
      console.log("sdfsdfs   " + data);
      if(data == true){  //is this correct if I json_encode(true) in login.php?
        console.log("sdfsdfs   " + data);
        form.submit();
      } else
      {
        alert('Please log in again, credentials did not match');
      }
    },
   error: function(data) 
   { 
     alert('Please log in again, credentials did not match...' );
     console.log(data);
   } 
 });  
 return false;
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
   <form action="crud.html" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return validateLogIn(this);">
.....
```

and my login.php code:

```
 <?php
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password']; 
 $login = $_POST['login'];

 if ($_POST['login'] == 'login') //check if the submit button is pressed
 {
   $remember = $_POST['remember'];  
   if ($username&&$password) //check if the field username and password have values
   {
     $dbhost = 'localhost';
     $dbuser = 'root';
     $dbpass = '';

     $connect=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die("Unable to Connect");
     echo "11..";
     mysqli_select_db($connect,"clients") or die("Could not open the db");
     echo "22..";
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients.users WHERE username='$username'";
     $login = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
     echo "33..";
     if (mysqli_num_rows($login))
     {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($login)) 
        {
            $db_password = $row['password']; 
            if ($password==$db_password)
            {   
                $loginok = TRUE;
                echo json_encode(true);  //is this correct??
            } else {
              echo json_encode(false);               
            }      
         ......
```

what have i got wrong please?

Comment: Look at server logfile, to find out what is happend.

Comment: I guess the error is thrown because you have specified the dataType as 'json' but I don't see you making json anywhere

Comment: use this in your error section of ajax function , so you will be able to get the error and handle the error .    error:function(xhr, errorStatus, errorThrown){ console.log(errorThrown); }

Comment: thanks i get a syntax error on line:  console.log(errorThrown);     it says Unexpected token < {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}message: "Unexpected token <" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript console would probably tell you more, I imagine. Or you could look at the error status:

```
error: function(data, status, errorString)
{ 
    console.log(data, status, errorString);
}
```

Comment: thanks i still get the sytax error Unexpected token < {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}message: "Unexpected token <" on the line:  console.log(data, status, errorString);

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `echo "33..";` in your php script.

Secondly: do not store passwords directly in your DB!